# Внешние ключи Sqlite и EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql

возникла такая проблема, есть БД у в ней есть 3 таблицы: users, DataAboutGame,QiwiPayment. Как с помощью внешнего ключа построить зависимость между этими таблицами. То есть users основная, а остальные зависимые. Использую Sqlite. Допустим если в таблице users есть user_id пользователя, то как сделать добавление "Сумму ставки" в таблицу DataAboutGame по ключу из users?

```
public partial class User
{
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public decimal GeneralPay { get; set; }

    public virtual DataAboutGame DataAboutGame { get; set; }
    public virtual QiwiPayment QiwiPayment { get; set; }
}

public partial class DataAboutGame
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public decimal SumBet { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Например добавление ставки в базу данных

```
    public static async Task<int> AddSumBetAsync(int userId, decimal sumBet)
    {
        await using (var db = new DBTelegramContext())
        {
            var user = await db.DataAboutGames.Where(x => x.User.UserId == userId).FirstAsync();
            user.SumBet = sumBet;
            return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы по идее можете сгененировать модель по вашей базе и не париться

Comment: `user.DataAboutGame.SumBet = sumBet;`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, почему именно так нужно делать?

Comment: Потому что именно так у вас задан набор классов